# Array declaration

Tags: c, arrays

Consider the following declaration:

```
char *name[]={"John","Beckham"};
```

Is this considered as 2D Array or not?

Because my professor told me that it's not 2D array but something else,

and if yes ..we can say that we can declare 2D array without specifying dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

It is an array of `char*`. It's length is 2. The first element is a pointer which points to the string literal "John", and the second is a pointer which points to the string literal "Beckham".

The entire structure is two-dimensional, in the sense that two numbers specify the location of one of the `char` elements (for example, the character 'k' is located at (1,3)). But it is not *rectangular,* so it does not have a simple size like [2, 7] (since there is no (0,4) element). It is *not* what people usually refer to when they talk about a "two-dimensional array".

Comment: This is the best answer so far. The declaration has some characteristics of a 2D array, e.g. it's valid to write `char c=name[0][2];`, but it's not what most C programmers think of as the canonical 2D array. I would refer to it as a ragged 2D array, or more accurately as a 1D array of pointers to strings.

Answer (score 2):

Of course your professor is right.  An array named `Arr` of type `T` might look like

```
T Arr [] = { ... };
```

In this case, `T` is the type `char *`, and the brackets `[]` denote an array of `char *`s.

The difference relies on the fact that a pointer is not an array.

See the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/) for information on the differences.